# Login loop issue in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, login, gui

I updated from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 about 4 months ago and it worked properly for a while, but then I started getting a problem with a login loop. I can drop down into the command line and run commands, but I want to login into the GUI environment.

Emby was put on an old Windows 8 converted to 10 computer that I used.

ASUS M Series M51AC
Tower
Core i7 4770 3.4 GHz
RAM 16 GB
HDD 1 TB
BIOS Version: 0901
SN:  XXXXXXXXXXXX

Display Hardware:

Results of `lspci | grep VGA`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 620 OEM] (rev a1)
```

Kernel Driver:

Results of  `find /dev -group video`

```
/dev/dri/card0    
/dev/dri/renderD128    
/dev/fb0
```

What x.org is using:

Results of `egrep -i " connected|card detect|primary dev|Setting driver" /var/log/Xorg.0.log`

```
[    70.690] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer X223W (CRT-1): connected
[    71.191] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer X223W (CRT-1): connected
[    95.213] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Acer X223W (CRT-1): connected
```

Linux OS:

Results of `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

IP Address:

Results of `dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com`

```
xx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

I have tried fixing this several times, but haven't been able to fix it. I do have the IP address.